# Pandoc: Format Chapters/Sections

Tags: pdftex, templates, pandoc

I'm currently using a basic template found on [internet](http://pastebin.com/SW2RfdkD) and I'm trying to format chapters and sections but nothing happens :(.
I include this to my template tex file and update usepackage:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}
{\LARGE\thechapter}
{1ex}
{\titlerule[2pt]
\vspace{2ex}%
\LARGE}
[\vspace{1ex}%
{\titlerule[2pt]}]

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\fontsize{14}{16}\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\titlerule\\}[\vspace{2pt}\titlerule]
```

Could someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to add option explicit to `\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}`